# Amazon MWS Marking order as shipped

Tags: amazon-mws

I have listed all of my Amazon orders to my site.
Now, i want to have ability to mark order as shipped from my site and the status will be instantly updated on amazon.
I have looked at amazon feed api but not clear about the format of feed xml.

I just want an example feed xml for updating order status.
( actually i want to know which parameters in xml feed should i send to mark order status as shipped.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you search for `Ship and Confirm Shipment (and get paid) - Order Fulfillment` on Seller Central it will bring you to a page that provides the XSD and a sample XML file for this feed.

The XML is provided below per your request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>My Store</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
           <MerchantOrderID>1234567</MerchantOrderID>
           <MerchantFulfillmentID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentID>
           <FulfillmentDate>2002-05-01T15:36:33-08:00</FulfillmentDate>
           <FulfillmentData>
               <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
               <ShippingMethod>Second Day</ShippingMethod>
               <ShipperTrackingNumber>1234567890</ShipperTrackingNumber>
           </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
               <MerchantOrderItemID>1234567</MerchantOrderItemID>
               <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
               <Quantity>2</Quantity>
           </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

From the documentation:

> Once you've shipped the order, send Amazon a shipping confirmation with fulfillment information

Comment: I checked 'I want to use an application to access my Amazon seller account with MWS'. It asks Application Name and Application's Developer Account Number. How do I create MWS Application's Developer Account ?

Comment: @SoorajlalKG - If you select I want to use an application, it expects you to be provided that information by the developer - if you are the developer you need to select "I want to develop..." or the similar option (been years since I've gone through this - you may want to read up on the docs to be certain)

Comment: As per doc,MerchantFulfillmentID is Seller-supplied unique identifier. What to put in this argument?Can we pass any unique number?

Comment: You'll have to create a new question @SoorajlalKG.

Comment: Hello Robert, can you explain bit more like what would be URL to post above XML ? @RobertH

Comment: @NaveedMetlo take a look at the documentation, if you still have questions, please create a new question for assistance.

Answer (score 5):

The MWS documentation is spead over a number of PDF documents. The XML feed formats are described in depth in [Selling on Amazon: Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf).

Comment: Hazzit, thanks, i just read that xml guide, and its good enough for me to understand.
Thanks

Comment: @malikGee since you seem to be new to StackOverflow: Please click the "up" arrow for all answers you find helpful, click the green checkmark for the one that you feel answers your question best.

Comment: @Hazzit-- as i'm new to stackoverflow, so i don't have enough reputation to  use up arrow,,, hope i'll be using up arrows soon,, :)